# How many bytes transfered in WCF before I should use streaming?

Tags: c#, wcf, streaming, filesize

I have a client application that talks to an updater service to download files. The updater service gets them from a database, then sends them to the client using WCF. At the moment, I am using WSHttpBinding so I can take advantage of the security. So the biggest file I have been downloading/sending is around 8 MB, and this works fine. I recently tried it with a file that was around 130 MB, but nothing happened on the client; the Network Usage just sat at 0%.

I assume the file is too large to transfer without streaming (maxReceivedMessageSize, etc., is equal to 209715200, so I know the settings are right for it). To fix this, I want to have the service use BasicHttpBinding so I can stream the file if it is bigger than a certain size.

My question is, at what size file should I switch over from WSHttpBinding to BasicHttpBinding and streaming? Is there some sort of standard that one should follow? Or is my logic here completely wrong anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no hard rule or formula to compute this - as per usual, *it depends* on your circumstances.

Consider this:

- your service typically can serve multiple callers simultaneously (depending on your throttling settings) - assume 10 or 20 simultaneous callers for now
- if each of these callers wants to download a file, the entire file needs to be buffered in your WCF service's memory if you're not using streaming

So if 20 callers try to download a 100 MB file each at the same time, your server side machine would have to be able to use 2 GB of RAM at once. Can your server handle that besides all its other usual processes running?

With this simple calculation, you can probably make a reasonable guesstimate as to that the size limit is in your case where switching to streaming makes sense.

Comment: Okay, but since the service is getting the file from my SQL database for every caller, even with streaming won't it still need the full 100MB file in memory for each caller(20 callers = still 2GM of RAM)? Is there a way I can just use the WCF service as a "bridge" from the database to the client without actually needing it to get the full file in memory? Or can I somehow get only one copy in memory and keep it there until all callers are done receiving it?

Answer (score 1):

As marc_s says, it depends on your site activity and available memory.

As a personal rule, I typically start considering streaming once the average size starts to get to around 1Mb. 5Mb is my "must stream" limit.